# Developing a simple JDBC servlet log-in application for a web project but can't validate user credentials

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

Let me begin by saying that I am not a developer by profession and that this is just something I am learning to do out of interest and too much free time. I am a beginner and I needed to get that out of the way in case I get flack for asking such a simple question.

I am trying to make a "Choose Your Own Adventure" web game, incorporating a login feature for practice. I am using Eclipse Mars, running on Tomcat 8.0. I created a table in my MySql database called PLAYER with the fields id, username, and password. So far, I've created the following files: index.html (which houses the login form), menu.html (the landing page after successful login), and Login.java (a servlet to handle database connection and user authentication).

Here's a portion of the index.html:

```
<form method="post" action="Login">
    <div class="form_layout">
        <label>User name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="uname" style="width:100%"/>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pword" style="width:100%"/>
        <input type="submit" id="login_btn" value="LOGIN" />
</div>      
</form>
```

Here is all of Login.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;

@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String username = request.getParameter("uname");
    String password = request.getParameter("pword");

    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/game"+"?verifyServerCertificate=false"+"&useSSL=true";
    String user = "root"; 
    String pass = "password";
    String sql = "SELECT username, password FROM player WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    boolean login = false;

    try {
        Class.forName(driver); 
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, username);
        statement.setString(2, password);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        login = resultSet.next();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException("Login failed", e);
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    }

    if (login) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("username", username); 
        response.sendRedirect("menu.html");
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("message", "Unknown username/password, try again");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request, response);
    }
}

}
```

Every time I try to log in, I always get redirected to index.html, whether or not the credentials I put in are correct. I tried changing this:

```
else {
    request.setAttribute("message", "Unknown username/password, try again");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request, response);
}
```

to this:

```
else {
    request.setAttribute("message", "Unknown username/password, try again");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("menu.html").forward(request, response);
}
```

to see if the redirects were working and found that it bypasses the if statement and proceeds right to else. I guessed that 'login' did not return true, and that's why it won't redirect the way I want it to. Looking at the code now, I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've scoured the internet for answers, but I've come up with nothing that fixed this for me.

Any sort of help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you added a record in your PLAYERS table that matches the credentials you are using?

Comment: Also just a suggestion. Logging helps a lot with debugging. I suggest using some kind of logging tool. Until then you can just use System.out.println("your message here"); That way you can print out the value of login and other variables. Even better than that would be to use debug mode in eclipse. If you don't know how to do that yet then the System.out.println method is the easiest.

Comment: Saying "I'm a beginner" doesn't give you any special privileges. Most of the questions are from beginners, and it's very obvious. The rules of the site are the same for all, so as long as you abide by them everything is fine.

Comment: @JoshChappelle Yes, I have. Let me try logging and see what's wrong. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: @Kayaman I wasn't expecting special treatment. I'm sorry if my opening statement implied that I was. I just didn't want people to give me answers that were beyond what I can currently understand. I know very little compared to everybody else on this site, and I didn't want to be made felt stupid for not knowing the solution to this problem right away. Thank you though. Feels nice to know everyone's treated equal here.

Comment: @Perdomoff Login does not return true even when the credentials I input match what's stored in the database, redirecting me to the index page every time instead of to menu.html. There has to be something wrong with my code but I can't quite figure out where.

Comment: How are you comparing the login credentials entered with what is coming from the db?

Comment: Show me an input example that fails and the correct credentials from the db

Comment: @Perdomoff Username is user1, password is pword1. I enter these exact same credentials, I am redirected back to the same login page from where I started. Same thing happens when I enter the wrong credentials like asdfg for username and 12345 for password.

Comment: Lets see what login is holding, place a print statement under where you're calling the resultset  method:

login = resultSet.next();
System.out.println(login);

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Perdomoff Yes! Turns out that while my query was correct, the ResultSet returned empty because for some reason, the value from input name = "pword" could not be read (returning null when I tried to print its value to the console), not finding a match in the database. Thought it had something to do with the input being type password (which is weird because it should work that way). What I did was I changed input type to text, and that worked, except the characters in my the password field on my form could be seen. Changed it back to input type = password, and that somehow fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

(this is not  direct answer to your question, but I don't have enough reputation to comment)

Implementing login by your own is a security risk. The user could enter the /menu.html url and will see the page without login ("deeplink").
Another problem here is the storage of the plain passwords. Its better to save a hash.

Tomcat offers a login mechanism: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html

In the web.xml you can define protected areas, which can only be accessed authenticated users.
For authentication you can use the JDBCRealm, which performs a user-lookup in the database.

Comment: This is interesting! I was thinking about this particular risk while I was doing the code for Login but I was more focused on the fact I couldn't get it to redirect where I want it to. Thanks for the suggestion! Will definitely look into that as soon as I get this sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. The query was correct, but the ResultSet returned empty because for some reason, the value from input name = "pword" could not be read (returning null when I tried to print its value to the console), therefore not finding a match in the database. Thought it had something to do with the input being type password (which is weird because it should work that way). What I did was I changed input type to text, and that worked, except the characters in my the password field on my form could be seen. Changed it back to input type = password, and that somehow fixed my problem. No idea why that happened, but the redirects are working now. Thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score -1):

I found another thing: 
the input elements in the form do not have names. The servlet tries to get them from request by their id, but what gets submitted in the request is the name of the input element.

---

outdated (wrong) idea:

I think now I found the mistake: you are comparing Strings in your query with "=" in sql it is LIKE...

```
String sql = "SELECT username, password FROM player WHERE username LIKE ? AND password LIKE ?";
```

Comment: No, it's only `LIKE` when you use wildcards. `=` works for exact match which is what is wanted here.